# BlackBerry background service in C#

Tags: blackberry, c#-4.0, service, background

Need assistance to develop background service on Blackberry with C#, how to?
Please help, i would really appreciate any assistance.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: could you give a little more details? An example would help.

Comment: I need to develop something like, windows service on BlackBerry - something that will know when message arrived, battery low/high and so on i will have to connect to other computer via http requests, but i have to that my program will run in background all the time.
And the user wouldn't be able to delete the program without my premmission.

Comment: You can do all that, but not in C#.

Comment: Where can i get the reference on how to do it?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't develop for BlackBerry in C#. At present you're only option is Java Micro Edition with BlackBerry Extensions.

Comment: where can i get examples of step by step tutorials?